# В чём может быть проблема?

Tags: java

Есть сайт на котором можно оплатить какую либо услугу с помощью Tinkoff банка+ можно оплатить через google pay.
Сайта встроенный в приложение я так понимаю встроенный следующим образом, основной url парситься с помощью retrofita а взаимодействует с помощью javascripta.
Если на сайте при попытке оплатить услугу с помощью tinkoff банка есть возможность выбрать способ оплаты google pay, который предоставляет сам tinkoff банк, то в приложение этой возможности нету!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот в android приложение оплатить через google pay возможности нету
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите в чём проблема?

Comment: В вопросе не видно вопроса. Раскройте что происходит, что должно происходить и прочую информацию - что используется в коде и как, покажите код. В данный момент ничего вам ответить нельзя, т.к. не на что отвечать.

Comment: Даже при попытке открыть url оплаты в простом web view приложение там нет возможности выбрать google pay, через браузер на ПК такая возможность есть!

Comment: Попробуйте открыть ссылку в браузере а не в webView. Если и там проблема будет, то, видимо, каких-то Кук или параметров в адресе не хватает. Ну или в ТП автора платежной системы надо обратиться

Comment: В браузере с моб телефона тоже нет возможности оплатить с помощью google pay.

Comment: @DENGI PAY вы решили свою проблему? столкнулся с тем же